# Show that the polynomial $x^4 - 4x^3 + 6$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that the polynomial $x^4 - 4x^3 + 6$ is irreducible in
>   $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

**Theorem :** Let $A$ an integral domain and $I$ a proper ideal of $A$. If $f(x) \not \equiv a(x)b(x) \pmod I$ for any polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$ $\in A[x]$ of degree $\in [1, \deg(f))$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $A[x]$

I think I have to use the previous theorem, but I don't know how to use it. Is anyone could help me at this point?

Comment: Apply Eisenstein with $p=2$.

Comment: Can you at the very least check the hypotheses of the theorem?

Comment: @Taj Your theorem is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the polynomial modulo $4$ to get the polynomial $x^4+2\in\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Observe that this polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Argue that the polynomial cannot be factored as the product of two irreducible quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and hence is irreducible there. Conclude using the theorem.

Comment: The theorem posted by the OP is wrong, and reducing modulo a non-prime ideal can lead to false conclusions. For instance, the polynomial $f=2x+2$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z$ and irreducible modulo $3$.

Comment: Moreover, in your case the polynomial $x^4+2$ could be written as a product of polynomials of degree higher than two since $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is not an integral domain. But let's suppose that you started with a decomposition of $f$ as a product of two polynomials of degree two (why not of degree one and three?). You still have to show that this leads to a contradiction modulo $4$.

Comment: Until you give a full proof (-1).

Answer (score 1):

May be you should solve for $a,b$ in

$x^4-4x^3+6=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+6)\Rightarrow a+b=-4; 7+ab=0; 6a+b=0$

$x^4-4x^3+6=(x^2+ax-1)(x^2+bx-6)\Rightarrow ??$

$x^4-4x^3+6=(x^2+ax+2)(x^2+bx+3)\Rightarrow ??$

$x^4-4x^3+6=(x^2+ax-2)(x^2+bx-3)\Rightarrow ??$